# Function for manipulating container of Base/Derived objects

Tags: c++, generics, stl, templates

consider the following algorithm with arrays:

```
class MyType;
{
    // some stuff
}

class MySubType:MyType
{
    // some stuff
}

void foo(MyType** arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0;i<len;i++)
        // do something on arr[i]->
}

void bar()
{
    MySubType* arr[10];
    // initialize all MySubType*'s in arr
    foo(&arr, 10);
}
```

Nothing too fancy here.  My question is - how do I do this with templates?

```
void foo(std::vector<MyType>& s)
{
    std::vector<MyType>::iterator i;
    for (i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
        // do stuff on *i
}
```

so, in bar, I can't do this:

```
void bar()
{
    std::vector<MySubType> s;
    foo(s);  // compiler error
}
```

error: invalid initialization of reference of type `std::vector<MyType, std::allocator<MyType> >&` from expression of type `std::vector<MySubType, std::allocator<MySubType> >`

Is there some way to do something like this?

Basically, if there's a way to do this:

```
std::vector<MySubType> s;
std::vector<MyType>& t = s;
```

I'd be happy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might fix your problem

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T>& s)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator i;
    for (i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
        // do stuff on *i
}
```

Comment: I like this, but had to change it a bit.
I put typename before T in template <T>
and I also had to put typename before std::vector ... don't know why...not very good with templates

Comment: The reason you had to put "template<typename T>" is that there are two kinds of template parameters: types and integers, and you have to say which kind is T.  You had to put "typename std::vector<T>::iterator i" because the compiler can't tell that "...::iterator" is a type without help--without "typename" it thinks that "iterator" is a data member of vector<T>.

Comment: sorry yes it's right it should be "template <typename T>", I wrote too much C# recently :P

Comment: Although this will work, it might be better to consider using a vector<MyType*> instead, which would then allow the vector to contain objects of MyType or any of its derived types, but nothing else. (You would then need to manually copy the vector<MySubType*> to a vector<MyType*> to pass to foo(), however.)

Comment: yeah, I had something like that, but I found myself copying and pasting the loop construct...every time I copy and paste code I think gee - I should probably put this in a common function...but thanks j_random_hacker

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [kuoson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775325/how-do-i-do-this-in-c/775343#775343), the idiomatic C++ style is to pass iterators to a function rather than containers.

```
template<typename Iterator>
void foo(const Iterator & begin, const Iterator & end)
{
    Iterator i;
    for (i = begin;  i != end;  ++i)
        // do stuff on *i
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem with this - if s and t point to the same object, what's to stop you putting `MyOtherSubType` (not related to MySubType) into into t? That would make s contain objects that are not MySubType. I don't know of any type-safe programming language that lets you do this. If it were allowed, imagine the problems we'd have:

```
//MySubType inherits from MyType
//MyOtherSubType also inherits from MyType

std::vector<MySubType> s;
std::vector<MyType>& t = s;

MyOtherSubType o;
t.push_back(o);
```

Since t and s are exactly the same object under different names, the element at s[0] is something that is not MySubType. Huge problem - we could never be sure that our vectors contained the types they are supposed to! Thus, the compiled disallows it.

Comment: There are a number that do support this type of covariance, just not C++

Comment: But I don't know of any ;-) Of course, weakly-typed languages like python will let you, but is there any type-safe language that lets you?

Comment: Java does, but you must specify whether you're doing covariance or contravariance. Effective Java introduces the "PECS" concept: producer extends, consumer super. What that means is this (if you're dealing with type T): if an incoming container is used for getting items out of (container used as producer), you specify this as "Collection<? extends T>"; if it's used for putting items into (container used as consumer), then you specify this as "Collection<? super T>".

Comment: Obviously, if a function needs to take a collection both to get items out of it, and to put items back in, then the type would be invariant ("Collection<T>"). :-P

Comment: C# in .Net 4.0 does also - you have to specify whether you are doing "in" (covariant) or "out" (contravariant)

Comment: well, that makes sense as to why I can't do it - thanks, but it still doesn't solve what I'm trying to do...

Comment: @Smashery: Your point is moot because you should not be using std::vector<MyType> at all if you want to store more than that exact concrete type (as the OP clearly does) -- you should be using std::vector<MyType*>.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say, "Nothing too fancy here", I'm not sure you realize this:

Your original code is broken; or if you're lucky it might not be broken right now, but it's quite fragile and will break as soon as someone does something more than look at the `MySubType` class.

The problem is that you're passing a `MyType*` to `foo()` but it really points to an array of `MySubType`.  If a `MySubType` object happens to be larger than a `MyType` object (which is pretty likely if you've added anything to the derived class), then the pointer arithmetic done in the `foo()` function will be incorrect.

This is one of the serious and classic pitfalls of arrays of derived class objects.

Comment: oh, yeah, your right, sorry - I meant to do this with an array of pointers

Comment: +1. The OP has corrected the problem with the original pointer-based code, but it remains with the vector-based code -- as a first step, you need to declare the vectors as vector<MyType*> and vector<MySubType*> respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store objects of multiple different `MyType`-derived types inside a single vector (as I suspect you do, although that's not necessary for this particular example), you'll need to use a `std::vector<MyType*>` instead of `std::vector<MyType>`.  This suggestion is analogous to that proposed by Michael Burr for your original pointer code.

This does have the unfortunate side-effect that you cannot implicitly convert a `std::vector<MySubType*>` to a `std::vector<MyType*>` to call `foo()` with.  But the conversion code is not too onerous:

```
void foo(std::vector<MyType*>& s)
{
    ...
}

void bar()
{
    std::vector<MySubType*> s;

    // Populate s
    ...

    std::vector<MyType*> u(s.begin(), s.end());    // Convert
    foo(u);
}
```

Or, just have `bar()` use a `std::vector<MyType*>` from the beginning.

Comment: thanks j_random_hacker...this is a decent solution, but I prefer the template function better...I also failed to mention that I'm not actually doing this on a std::vector, but on something like a std::vector.  The items in the special container cannot be pointers by design (they all must at least be a specific type, which is not a pointer).  I didn't explain this in my original post because it's too much typing to explain. :(

Comment: No problem :) If the elements are stored as objects rather than pointers to them, then *every* function that you want to operate on a variety of types (e.g. both MyType and MySubType) will need to be made into a function template.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not support covariance on template types, any more than C# currently does, much for the same reasons. If you want to do this, it is best to make your vector be templatised on a common interface type (of pointers to that type), and make the function foo accept a vector of that type.

Comment: All the time? Really? You can assign between templated classes where the template parameters are not the same?

Comment: Needs to be vector of base-class pointers to work. And since STL and raw pointers are ill adviced, smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't. Different template specialisations are considered different classes; you can't convert between `std::vector<MyType>` and `std::vector<MySubType>`.

You could split the "do stuff" common bit of `foo()` into a separate function and have a separate loop over each vector (or possibly use `std::foreach`).

Answer (score 0):

Using boost (for smart pointer):

```
foo( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyType> >& v )
{
   std::for_each( v.begin(),
                  v.end(),
                  do_something );
}

bar()
{
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyType> > s;
    // s.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<MyType> ( new MySubType() ) );
    foo( s ); 
}
```

Comment: Boost for smart pointers, pointer to base class solves the prob.

Answer (score 0):

If I'd know what's the real code behind those foobars then maybe I'd know better, but isn't there already a solution for your problem in the STL?

```
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), DoStuffOnI());
```

Just put your "do stuff on *i" code in a function or a functor:

```
struct DoStuffOnI : public std::unary_function<MyType&,void> {
    void operator()(MyType& obj) {
        // do stuff on *i
    }
};
```

If you're bothered about sending away two parameters instead of one, then ok, maybe you can do something like:

```
template<typename In>
struct input_sequence_range : public std::pair<In,In> {
    input_sequence_range(In first, In last) : std::pair<In,In>(first, last)
    {
    }
};

template<typename C>
input_sequence_range<typename C::iterator> iseq(C& c)
{
    return input_sequence_range<typename C::iterator>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename In, typename Pred>
void for_each(input_sequence_range<In> r, Pred p) {
    std::for_each(r.first, r.second, p);
}
```

Then call for_each like so:

```
for_each(iseq(s), DoStuffOnI());
```

Comment: I like this, but I think the template solution from kuoson is more elegant.  Thanks wilhelmtell.